# Decomposition of Vector into n vectors (with length conditions)

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

If i have a vector `V` and i want to decompose it to `n` vectors their lengths are $L_1, L_2, L_3, .. L_n$

Where $\ \vec{V}= \vec{V_1} + \vec{V_2} + .... + \vec{V_n}$

for `n` equals to `2` i will get 2 solutions by extracting the angle from the equation:

$\ V^2 = V_1^2 + V_2^2 + V_1*V_2*cos(\angle(\mathbf{\vec{V_1}},\mathbf{\vec{V_2}}))$

How can i find all solutions for an $\ n > 2$ ?

[image]

Comment: How do you know there are any solutions? You can't decompose a length-100 vector into 73 vectors, each of length 1.

Comment: i could be misusing some terms, so i edited my question & added an image.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right, not always there's a solution for each {V, Ln} set but if there're solutions how to get them ?

Comment: In many situations, there will be infinitely many solutions. You can take all but two of the vectors to be arbitrary vectors of the appropriate length, and then solve for the last two.

Comment: if i took some arbitrary vectors, it would end in a no-solution case in many situations.

Comment: My advice is to take a simple case, say, take vectors of lengths 7, 8, 9, and 10, and see how many quadrilaterals you can form with them, and how it goes trying to describe them all. You will then have a good picture of how the general problem goes.